# How to edit css modules in react

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have the following files:

## Test.js:

```js
import React from 'react';
import style from './style.module.css'
        
        
function Test() {
    return(<div className={style.classcolor}>Test</div>);
}
export default Test;
```

## style.module.css

```css
.classcolor
{
    background-color:blue;
}
```

Is there a way to change the css attributes inside the js file, similar to the code below?

```js
style.classcolor.backgroundColor ="red";
```

Comment: and this did not work? the one you are suggesting?

Comment: @HadiPawar no when i try it gives me this output TypeError: Cannot create property 'BackgroundColor' on string 'style'

Comment: @AndriNic Have you tried my examples, should I improve my answer?

Answer (score 0):

An option is to use a variable and change the class depending on it:

```js
class Test extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { orange: true }
  }
  toggleClass = () => {
    this.setState({ orange: !this.state.orange })
  }
  render() {
    const { orange } = this.state
    return (
      <div>
        <div className={orange ? 'orange' : 'red'}>Test</div>
        <button onClick={this.toggleClass}>Toggle class</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Test />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```css
.orange{
  color: orange;
}

.red{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="react"></div>
```

A not really react way is to use `element.style`, [more information](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_style.asp):

```js
document.getElementById('test').style.color = 'orange';
```

```html
<div id="test">Test</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add array [0] after get the className, and then you can access the style from DOM

```js
document.getElementsByClassName(style.classcolor)[0].style.backgroundColor = 'red'
```

Answer (score -1):

You can see this library [styled-component](https://styled-components.com/), you can pass props for the component and by the value of the prop, you decide in how the style will be.